# How to use Texture2DArray in HLSL DirectX11 C++

Tags: c++, directx, shader, hlsl

I'm just wondering how I can use Texture2DArray in HLSL.

I am trying to implement a model loader where models have different amount of textures. At the moment my HLSL uses Texture2D with a size of 2 (texture and normal textures) but as my models have varying amounts of textures, I am looking to use Texture2DArray but have no clue where to start. I've been trying to find examples and such on the internet but have had no luck :(

I load in textures which are compiled to 'ID3D11ShaderResourceView*' so should I create a variable ID3D11ShaderResourceView** which I create an array of points to textures then pass that to the shader or what?

Any help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need only set the `ArraySize` field of `D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC` when you create it.

One `ShaderResourceView` views the entire array, you don't need multiple views. If you're not providing your own `D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC` on creation (and instead passing nullptr) then you're already set.

If you are passing your own `D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC` then set the `ViewDimension` field to `D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2DARRAY`, then fill out all 4 members of the `Texture2DArray` field of the view description (`MostDetailedMip`, `MipLevels`, `FirstArraySlice`, `ArraySize`).

In HLSL you just need to specify:

`Texture2DArray myTexture;`

instead of

`Texture2D myTexture;`

and when sampling, uv coordinates are three dimensional. x and y are as normal, but z is the index of the slice of the array you want to read from.

If you're initialising your textures on creation using a `D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA` structure, then you simply need to pass a pointer to an array of `D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA`'s, one for each slice in the array.